# How do I limit the x and y axes when plotting Association Rules?

Tags: r, arules

I am currently trying to plot some association rules with confidence as the y-axis and support as the x-axis. However, I want to limit the y-axis range to be 0 to 1, and the x-axis range to be 0 to 0.3. I've tried using xlim and ylim, however, when I write this:

plot(myRules, measure = c("support", "confidence"), shading = "lift", xlim =c(0,0.3), ylim =c(0,1))

I get the following error:

Warning: Unknown control parameters: xlim, ylim

I've looked this up and can't find any example where limiting axes range for association rules visualization or this error is addressed. How do I fix this?

Comment: Could you please share your data using `dput(myRules)`? So we can help you better.

Comment: What is the class of `myRules` and what package is the `plot` method coming from for that class?

Comment: @GregorThomas

myRules was created using apriori()

myCC <- read.csv("CoffeeChainAR.csv")
myRules <- apriori(myCC, parameter = list(support = 0.001, confidence = 0.05))

I believe the plot method is coming frm ggplot2 package and arulesviz package? I'm new to r, so I apologize

Comment: If it's using ggplot then you would set the scale by adding to your plot `plot(myRules, measure = c("support", "confidence"), shading = "lift") + scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0, 0.3)) + scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 1)`. You may want to read through an introduction to ggplot to get used to how it works.

Comment: @Quinten I tried that command, and it gave me an enormous amount of data that I don't think would be able to fit here- like under 600 lines. Would that still be helpful?

Comment: You could also share the first values using `head(dput(myRules),20)`.

Comment: @GregorThomas Thank you so much! That worked, and yes, I'll get on that asap!

Answer (score 1):

We don't have your `myRules` object, but we can create something similar for demonstration purposes:

```r
library(arules)
library(arulesViz)
library(ggplot2)

data("Adult")

myRules <- apriori(Adult, parameter = list(support = 0.3))
```

The standard plot looks like this:

```
plot(myRules, measure = c("support", "confidence"), shading = "lift")
```

[image]

Note that in `arulesViz`, the generic `plot` function actually creates a `ggplot` object, so we are free to set our own scales and co-ordinates. To limit the x axis to be between 0 and 0.3, we can do:

```r
plot(myRules, measure = c("support", "confidence"), shading = "lift") +
  coord_equal(xlim = c(0, 0.3))
```

[image]

You can also add `, ylim = c(0, 0.3)` right after `xlim = c(0, 0.3)` if you want to limit the y axis too.

<sup>Created on 2022-04-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>